# image is not showing smaller as icon on browser chrome and fire fox browsers

Tags: php, html, css

I am facing an issue where few images are not properly shown on firefox, chrome, edge browser but internet explorer it perfectly fine. Some part of code is as below.[image: Big Image]

```css
.header_top-left1 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.header_top-left1 a {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.header_top-left1 a img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_top-left1">
  <a href="callto:"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="Call" />
    Call
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem isn't happening with the code you are showing us, so it must be something else.

Comment: @FluffyKitten: I have showend the code related to image only.

Comment: Yes, and that works as expected, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @fluffykitten: I am expecting smaller image but it is very large on chrome and firefox browser.

Comment: I've put your code into a snippet with a 350x300px image, and you can see that it works perfectly. The only change I made was to remove the PHP. There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, and we can't help fix a problem we can't see!

Comment: @FluffyKitten:   I tried similar solutions but nothing worked. You can check the link https://www.uatechuae.com  on bother broswer internet explorer and chrome.

Comment: We can't help if the question doesn't have the problem. Questions must include all of the relevant information here on Stack Overflow. Otherwise when you fix the problem other users can no longer see it, so your question becomes invalid and is no longer useful for future users.

Answer (score 0):

What i see on the first look is that you missing the units in width property.
Your code:

```
.header_top-left1 a img {
  width: 20; // hast to be 20px for example
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: That isn't the problem because the `height` is correct, but it is still being displayed larger than 15px.

Comment: @yalcin: I had added the units but issue is same. image is lager than expected.

Comment: @UmarAbdullah You are using an image or iconfont? Because when you run your code it works so its not a real szenario :)

Comment: "*Because when you run your code it works*" - that's why you should post an answer until we know what the problem is! We can't fix problems that don't exist :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though IE is ignoring the Fontawesome classes and just showing the png green backed phone image while the other browsers are attempting at least to use fa.

Your given code doesn’t show any setting up of the font. Is this done somewhere?

Comment: @Haworth: fontnawesome class i have removed. If i used fontawesome class image will be small but it will blured.